# What's the command for fractional scaling on Ubuntu 18.10 on xorg?

Tags: xorg, 18.10

I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux in general and have installed Ubuntu on my 2013 MBP. It's a 2880x1800 display, and so the scaling is a little goofy. 200% is a bit too zoomed in, but 100% is way too small. I did an install before and managed to get fractional scaling on Ubuntu before, but I can't remember it.

Anyone know the command to enable fractional scaling on 18.10 on xorg (not Wayland)?

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['scale-monitor-framebuffer']"`

Comment: I tried it in 18.10 live session with my sony tv 4k..but it showed 100 200 300 400

Comment: Yes, I don't think this is correct. I had someone on reddit tell me this only works on 19.04 and above.